# How is the opHash generated?

Tags: operation

Could someone give a step-by-step approach of how to go from the operation inputs (e.g. sender, receiver, amount etc) to generating an opHash for an operation? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This integration test from Taquito could serve as a good step-by-step reference of how you go from transaction inputs (in this case a smart contract call) to a signed operation and operation hash.

https://github.com/ecadlabs/taquito/blob/9f53873104ab170115dff744cf4266ef8ef24f98/integration-tests/call-contract-method-manual-steps.spec.ts#L8

Comment: this is perfect, thanks!